# Getting module (uvicorn) not found error in Python

Tags: pip, python-packaging, python-venv, python-poetry

I am running this command (`poetry run python3 myproject`) and I am getting below error.
I have installed *uvicorn* through *pip* but still getting the same issue.
Not sure if the command is skipping the virtual environment creation and hence not able to import *uvicorn*.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/var/app/GIT_CLONE/BioFi-Ai/projects/ai-analytics/ai_analytics/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import uvicorn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uvicorn'
```

I tried installing *uvicorn* through *pip* and I was able to install it successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yesterday i tried, pip3 install PyMySQL, had to use pip3.10 install PyMySQL

Comment: If your project uses *Poetry* as development workflow tool, then you should not _pip_-install anything, you should let *Poetry* take care of that, with `poetry add uvicorn` if I recall correctly. And then if things are done correctly you should probably do `poetry run myproject` I think. Because from the looks of the error message, in particular the `/usr/lib/python3.8` part, it seems like you are not running the *Python* interpreter from the virtual environment created by *Poetry*, so I guess your project and its dependencies (*uvicorn*, etc.) are not installed for `/usr/lib/python3.8`.